# Determining whether a point with unknown values is positive

Tags: calculus

I have 2 roots for a function:

$\Large x=\frac{-(1+b-m)\pm\sqrt{(1+b-m)^2-4dn}}{2d}$

Is it possible to determine whether a root is positive or negative given only that

$b,d,m,n > 0$

Comment: Are you also requiring the roots be real?

Comment: Real roots, yes.

Comment: The product of the two roots is $n/d$, so if they are real roots, they are either both positive or both negative...

Comment: It's all determined by whether $1+b-m$ is positive or negative. If $1+b-m$ is negative, both roots are positive. If $1+b-m$ is positive, then both roots are negative. Since both are possible, you can't conclude either way just given what you are given.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

The expression you give $$x_{\pm}=\frac{-(1+b-m)\pm\sqrt{(1+b-m)^2-4dn}}{2d}$$ are the roots of the quadratic equation $$d x^2+ (b-m+1)x+n=0$$ So their product is $\frac {n}{d}$

I am sure that you can take from here.